# How to read from file and put in an Array

Tags: swift

This is an application of Sieve of Eratosthenes written in Swift.
I'm able to write the output on a file, but I'm only able to start by manually passing [primesList].
Instead, I would like to read the file primesList.txt and put it in [primesList].

```
import Foundation

// set a file called test.txt on Desktop to be used by this program
let dir = "~/Desktop"
let file = "primesList.txt"
let path = dir.stringByExpandingTildeInPath
let filePath: NSString = path.stringByAppendingPathComponent(file)

// set some needed variables and constants
var highestNumberEvaluated = 100
var primesList = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97]

let readFromFile = String(contentsOfFile: filePath, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
println(readFromFile)

let inputNumber = 100
let range2Evaluate = 100
let last2Evaluate = inputNumber + range2Evaluate

println("Find primes between \(inputNumber) and \(last2Evaluate):\n")

// create a dictionary of numbers to be evaluated true or false
var numbersList = [Int: Bool]()
for i in inputNumber...last2Evaluate {
  numbersList[i] = true
}

// mark as not prime (false) all not primes in numbersList
for i in primesList {
  if i < Int(sqrt(Double(last2Evaluate))) {
    let myMultiplier = inputNumber / i
    var bottomValue = i * myMultiplier
    for var j = bottomValue; j < (bottomValue + range2Evaluate + 2); j += i {
      numbersList[j] = false
    }
  } else {break}
}

// create an array made by all primes found true, then sort
var primesFoundList = [Int]()
for (myKey, myValue) in numbersList {
  if myValue == true {
    primesFoundList.append(myKey)
  }
}
primesFoundList.sort { $0 < $1 }

// add the primes found to the original primes list and write on the file test.txt
primesList += primesFoundList
let toBeWritten = toString(primesList)
toBeWritten.writeToFile(filePath, atomically: true, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
```

on line 13-14 I can get the content of the file, how can I write this content in the array [primesList]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `toString()` function is not very well suited to produce output that is to be
read again. You could create a simple comma-separated list with

```
let toBeWritten = ", ".join(primesList.map { String($0)})
toBeWritten.writeToFile(filePath, atomically: true, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
```

which can be read again with

```
if let readFromFile = String(contentsOfFile: filePath, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil) {
    primesList = readFromFile.componentsSeparatedByString(",").map() { ($0 as NSString).integerValue }
}
```

(Note: This assumes that the file has the correct format, otherwise it may crash.)

Alternatively, use the `writeToFile()` method from `NSArray` which writes the
array as a property list (XML) file:

```
(primesList as NSArray).writeToFile(filePath, atomically: false)
```

which can be read back with

```
if let storedList = NSArray(contentsOfFile: filePath) as? [Int] {
    primesList = storedList
}
```

Comment: The first method return an EXC error at runtime. The second one is working properly. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @sabi: You are welcome. I had tested both methods. But the first one is not very robust: If the file already exists with the wrong format then it might crash. The second method is probably better.

Comment: I definitely agree with you, also because this way the program is very fast at writing the file. Once I set a good optimization level, I was able to get primes up to 20 000 000 in less than 10 seconds. However, I appreciated the first method for learning.